# SSRS report prints duplicate table when updating any record

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

SSRS report prints duplicate table when updating any record. When I initially save data, that particular record is saved to database  and prints table  with one row in SSRS report. However, if I update the record,  2 tables are generated on the report with updated values. I just want one table with updated values cause if we keep on updating our record and it keeps generating new table every time, the report is going to be too long. I am concerned if this might be issue with the design of the report or some other issue. I did not design the report, I am just trying to debug it.

The main report looks like this.
[image]

This is the subreport that is duplicating
[image]

And this is what is looks like when the report is run.
[image]

455 is first update, that created 2 tables but had updated record on both tables. 456 is the second update that created third table with updated data on all 3 tables. I just want one table with all the updated values

Comment: This is very vague.. what does the dataset return.. are you sure it is returning an entire table for each row or data?? screen shots and sample data would help

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NLvT1YogXU2emutxMXv7sxE97dLhXwWe   ( is what Main Report looks like)  , https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K7OLtb-9NkAh3BT2OxazYe2_MA4rXWzG (is the sub report that is duplicating data) , https://drive.google.com/open?id=12Jpb-Kud-PyE-IJB6R50l3keebmw7e5i (is what it looks like) .455 is first update, that created 2 tables but had updated record on both tables. 456 is the second update that created third table with updated data on all 3 tables. I just want  one table with all the updated values.

Comment: You can see that within the main report, there are 2 sub reports. The top sub report is generatin the warranty id, warrantor and explaination. This sub report is designed separtely and placed in the main report.

Comment: On the Main report.. where is the subreport placed? What grouping? The screen capture on the first Main Report does not show.

Comment: If you run the subreport on it's own.. do you still get the same result?

Comment: I suspect the dataset in the main report is returning the wrong data, more rows than you expect and each row is showing a subreport. If you can run your dataset take a look at the results in the dataset editor. If you can't for whatever reason then, as a quick check, just add a table to the start of your report with no group or anything else and then add the fields from your dataset so you can see exactly what is being produced.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p2C8jvFeZEd3G2LGivMUzeEBSj5rZcv4 (this is the sub report, [marked inside red]) or the sub report with the warranty information , thats creating duplicate table on report. The one just below it is another sub-report which is working fine.

Comment: Insert a line outside the details group and then place the sub report on that line and see what happens.